# How to postpone Spring application's registration in Eureka until the full initialization of the application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

In my Spring application, I want to do some preparation stuff (f.e., to warm up the caches) in `ApplicationReadyEvent` listeners before registering it in Eureka. The problem is that my application is made accessible in Eureka for other apps before it finishes the whole preparation, which can cause some problems later.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any convenient way to postpone the registration until the full initialization of the application.

What I've tried:

- I set `eureka.instance.initial-status` to anything but "up" (f.e., to "starting"), but, as I realized, Eureka's healthcheck comes into play and sets the current status to "up" even before `ContextRefreshedEvent` or so. In this case, I can disable the healthcheck by `eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled = false` but later I have to create the `EurekaHealthCheckHandler` bean while `ApplicationReadyEvent`, then register it into application context manually.
- Another approach is to set `spring.cloud.service-registry.auto-registration.enabled = false`. It seems that registration is caused later in this case (after all my `ApplicationReadyEvent` listeners) but `EurekaRegistration` bean isn't created automatically, so I've finished with creating it manually again (it will need for the application later).
- Also I've played with `eureka.*` interval properties (f.e. `eureka.initialInstanceInfoReplicationIntervalSeconds`). In this case, you need to be able to predict the final time that the preparation will take, which is unreliable, in my opinion.

So, anytime you need to set a bunch of properties correctly and then to create and configure a lot of things manually. Pretty cumbersome for (I think) the common task.

Is there any better approach? Maybe I'm missing something and the solution is on the surface?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.9 with Spring Cloud Greenwich.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Would setting `instanceEnabledOnit`to be false, with initial status being `OUT_OF_SERVICE`, then explicitly setting the status to UP after the application has started solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because of earlier initialization of healthcheck (status is changed from "out_of_service" to "up" by it almost immediately). `instanceEnabledOnit`, afaik, is false by default.